# How to pass an object to a GET request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi I'm currently trying to pass an object to a GET request for search filter in nodejs using express but I get a return of 404 GET /route1/search/[object%20Object] 404 1.148 ms - 38

I already try to log the result in the terminal using console.log(req.params.dataObject); or console.log(req.params.dataObject.option); but get the result of [Object, Object] or Undefined

```
router.get('/search/:dataObject',
 async function (req, res) {
    try {
      console.log(req.params.dataObject);
      res.status(200).json(searchPhone);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        error: err.message
      });
    }
  });
```

I expect the result to be {option: 'some data', keyword: 'some data'}

Comment: did you try `JSON.stringify()` and send that stringified object to the query param? later to use that you will just need to parse that particular query param.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't shove an object into a URL without encoding it somehow.  Whatever code is calling your server is attempting to do that, and JavaScript is converting the object to a string, which is where the `[object Object]` comes from.  This happens before your server ever gets to it.

What you should probably be doing instead is using the querystring.  This is a standard way for you pass in key/value parameters.  For example, your client would call:

```
GET /search?option=some%20data&keyword=some%20data
```

Then in your server, you could use:

```
req.query.option
req.query.keyword
```

Comment: Is that normal I get 404 response but req.query.option and keyword is now logging to the terminal GET /search?option=site&keyword=ssss 404 0.612 ms - 38

Comment: @ChristianAngeloMSulit Your code is set up for `/search/`, not `/search`.  You could modify it for either way.